# ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs parameter set-up

Tags: excel, vba

When I use `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` to overwrite a file the massage window comes up Yes or no.

How can I set up `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` to overwrite the already saved file whithout additional pushing yes or no?

Comment: Untested, but try `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` - can't remember if that will work in this case.

Comment: @BigBen it does [Application.DisplayAlerts property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.displayalerts) see the note in the box.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - yep, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off the alert using [Application.DisplayAlerts property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.displayalerts).

> *When using the **SaveAs** method for workbooks to overwrite an existing file, the **Confirm Save As** dialog box has a default of **No**, while the **Yes** response is selected by Excel when the **DisplayAlerts** property is set to **False**. The **Yes** response overwrites the existing file.*

Don't forget to turn them on again after you turned them off.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

---

#### Off Topic

Note that in most cases `ActiveWorkbook` is not what you need but `ThisWorkbook`.

- `ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook that has focus / is on top (this can easily change with a single mouse click.
- `ThisWorkook` is the workbook the current VBA code is in (this will never change).

Therefore `ThisWorkbook` is more reliable. And `ActiveWorkbook` is rarely needed (eg. if you write an add-in).